# I try to Run this Mobilenet script

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mobilenet

I am try to run this python code
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/mobilenet.py
But I can't able to do if any one help me to run it's appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if you are running tensorflow the mobileNet models can be obtained as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf
base_model=tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=False, weights="imagenet",input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max')
```

Keras applications has a wide range of models you can select. Documentation is
[here.](https://keras.io/api/applications/) Click on a model in the table and a window will open that shows how to get the model.